# finding print status when printing with PrintDialog

Tags: c#, printing

I have used PrintDialog to print some visual object.

```
PrintDialog printer = new PrintDialog();
printer.PrintVisual(barcodeCreator, "");
```

now i want to do some business logic if print is done successfully and some other logic if it is not done completely.
so how can I find the print status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [PrintDialog.PrintQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printqueue.aspx) property. It returns [PrintQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.aspx) object that represents the selected printer. You can then use the [PrintQueue.GetJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.getjob.aspx) method or [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue_properties.aspx).

Comment: PrintQueue.GetJob requires jobId but PrintDialog.PrintVisual do not return any thing. how can I find the job Id?

Comment: By using [PrintQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.getprintjobinfocollection.aspx) method